# Android App code design message handling for commands

Tags: java, android, multithreading, design-patterns

I'm having two main code design problems in my app.

My app mainly consists in sending ssh commands to a remote host.
Right now I have a separated thread (singleton) which gets messages through the handler which specifies which is the next command to be sent, or the username/password/ip (kind of messy but works...).

This approach works good for unidirectional commands, but I'm planning to make it bidirectional which I don't know how to implement. As far as I know Android doesn't allow to change UI elements by another thread so a listener pattern wouldn't be it.

Also, I just read that we shouldn't save things in the application object, which is also what I'm doing by saving whether my app is running full or lite mode... I don't know where should I save it in order to not make it obviously hackable (sqlite-SharedPrefs are easily editable...)

Answer (score 0):

Only a general hint: There is Activity.runOnUiThread() to execute code (later) on main thread.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I solved the problem with my thread by passing an object containing a listener and a command, and then executing it with runOn UiThread, wich by the way I don't understand why is not a static method since every activity is run within the UI thread. Thanks!